# Is it possible to serialize Map.keySet without copying the Set?

Tags: java, serialization

As we all know, KeySet of Map is not serializeable. But I have cases where I just want to send the KeySet of a Map wrapped in a custom Object over wire. So I have implemented the writeObject method to check for a serializable Set.

My question now is, if there is a way to get a binary representation without copying the whole Set into a new Set? This seems very inefficient to me since we have usually huge maps in this case (which one of the reasons we just send the keys and not the whole map).

```
public class Serialize2 implements Serializable {
    private static final Class TM_KS_CLASS = new TreeMap<>().keySet().getClass();
    private static final Class LM_KS_CLASS = new LinkedHashMap<>().keySet().getClass();

    private Set<String> testSet;
    public String justSomeOtherFieldToSerialize;

    public Serialize2(Set<String> testSet) {
        this.testSet = testSet;
    }

    public Set<String> getTestSet() {
        return testSet;
    }

    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream) throws java.io.IOException {
        if (!(testSet instanceof Serializable)) {
            if (testSet.getClass().equals(TM_KS_CLASS)) {
                testSet = new TreeSet<>(testSet);
            } else {
                testSet = new HashSet<>(testSet);
            }
        }

        stream.defaultWriteObject();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Serialize2{" +
                "testSet=" + testSet +
                '}';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> foo = new HashMap<>();
        foo.put("lala", 1);
        foo.put("lolo", 2);
        foo.put("lulu", 3);
        foo.put("lili", 4);

        Serialize2 sTest = new Serialize2(foo.keySet());
        Serialize2 dsTest = (Serialize2) SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.serialize(sTest));
        System.out.println(dsTest);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really make sense to me. If you serialize a key-set, send it over the wire, and deserialize it, then the result should be a key-set; but then that violates the contract of a key-set, since a key-set is supposed to be backed by a map, and you didn't send the map over the wire . . .

Comment: As soon as you send a KeySet over wire it is no longer tied to the map anyway and I really just need the keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, One way to do is to serialize each objects individually without copying into a new set,

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream) throws java.io.IOException {
    Iterator itr = testSet.iterator();
    if (testSet.getClass().equals(TM_KS_CLASS)) {
        stream.writeBoolean(true);
    } else {
        stream.writeBoolean(false);
    }
    stream.writeInt(testSet.size());
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        stream.writeObject(itr.next());
    }
    stream.writeObject(justSomeOtherFieldToSerialize);
}
```

You need to have corresponding readObject implementation that reads each object individually and puts in a set, for example,

```
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream) throws java.io.IOException {
    boolean bTypeofmap = stream.readBoolean(); // Whether its a TreeMap or LinkedhashMap
    int size = stream.readInt();
    testSet = new java.util.HashSet(size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        testSet.add(stream.readObject());
    }
    justSomeOtherFieldToSerialize = (String) stream.readObject();
}
```

Comment: Cool thanks! Can you just give me a hint how to handle other fields in the object (like the justSomeOtherFieldToSerialize field I have added in my Question)